# Как создать представление с добавлением связанных сущностей?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

Используется проект с ASP.Net Core 2.0 MVC с .Net Core и EF Core 2.0. Имеется сущность `Person` и `Phone` со связью "один-ко-многим", т.е. каждая сущность `Person` может содержать множество телефонов или ни одного. При генерации стандартного контроллера генерируется также представление. Проблема в том, что необходимо при создании сущности `Person` иметь возможность добавления телефона, одного или нескольких. Многодневный поиск ничего не дал, возможно из-за того, что не знаю как сие обозначить в поиске.

Каким образом создать представление с возможностью динамического добавления связанных сущностей?

Модель:

```
public partial class Person {

        public Person() {
            Phone = new HashSet<Phone>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Phone> Phone { get; set; }
    }
}

public partial class Phone {

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Type { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public int? PersonId { get; set; }

    public Person Person { get; set; }
}

public partial class ModelContext : DbContext {
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Person>(entity => {
            entity.Property(e => e.Name).HasMaxLength(50).IsRequired();
        });
        modelBuilder.Entity<Phone>(entity => {
            entity.HasOne(d => d.Person)
                .WithMany(p => p.Phone)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.PersonId)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_Phone_Person");
        });
    }
}
```

Автоматически сгенерированное представление:

```
@model xxx.Models.Person

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

<h4>Person</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
    <form asp-action="Create">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="FirstName" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="FirstName" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="FirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

---

**Обновление**

На данный момент использую такие "костыли".

В представлении Phone содержимое HTML-формы вынес в частичное представление:

```
...
<form asp-action="Create">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    @Html.Partial("_Create", Model)
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
</form>
...
```

В контролере проверяю тип запроса: если это AJAX-запрос, то возвращаю частичное представление, в противном случае - стандартное поведение:

```
// GET:  Emails/Create
public IActionResult Create(int? PersonId) {
    return Request.IsAjaxRequest()
           ? PartialView("_Create");
           : View();
}
```

Далее на стороне клиента выполняю AJAX-запросы, с помощью которых создаю модальный диалог добавления сущности, проверяю корректность данных и т.д. (AJAX-запросы указаны в порядке вызовов):

1. к контроллеру ([HttpGet] /Phones/Create) - для получения содержимого HTML-формы, которая используется в модальном диалоге;
2. к API ([HttpPost] /api/Phones/Verify) - для проверки созданной сущности, для чего отправляю JSON, созданный из элементов формы диалога;
3. к вспомогательным методам контроллера ([HttpGet] /Phones/GetPhoneList) - для получения списка/листа/HTML-разметки созданных сущностей и добавления в существующее представление;

В связи с чем возникает резонный вопрос: а не перемудрил ли я? Хотелось бы услышать хоть какое-либо мнение на этот счет. Из-за отсутствия ответов возникает такое ощущение, что я иду не в том направлении. Неужели никто не сталкивался с такой задачей? Как принято решать подобное в ASP.Net? Просмотрел уже несколько книг по ASP.Net и ASP.Net Core, но в них нет ни единого слова о подобной задаче/проблеме.

Comment: Вот [здесь смотрите](http://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/dbset/querying-data) как использовать `Include()` для запроса телефонов связанных с человеком. А [вот здесь смотрите](http://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/dbset/adding-data) как добавлять связанные данные в БД.

Comment: @Bulson скорее всего Вы не поняли вопроса: мне нужно создать представление (view).

Comment: Да, не понял. Думал у вас затык с работой в EF. Вам нужно исправить заголовок на: "Как создать представление (View) для добавления связанных сущностей?"

Answer (score 0):

Понятно что некропостинг, вдруг кому пригодится.
Долго искал решение в похожей задаче, подсказали мне такое:
State Management In ASP.NET
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/2072a9/state-management-in-Asp-Net/

Comment: Оформите как более развёрнутый ответ, старайтесь не использовать ссылки на сторонние ресурсы, т.к. они со временем могут стать недоступны

Comment: Каким образом приведённая Вами ссылка на статью, как и сама статья, могут помочь решить проблему?